# Removing all automatic migrations and creating code-based migrations in their place

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

As you're about to learn, I'm inexperienced with building applications using ASP.NET MVC, I'm deliberately coming out of my comfort zone in order to learn.

I'm using code-first migrations with Entity Framework, and I created a `Train.cs` model and used the `Enable-Migrations` command. For some reason I thought it would be a good idea to enable automatic migrations in `Migrations/Configuration.cs` and I continued developing with automatic migrations enabled for a while.

Then I read somewhere that automatic migrations are generally a bad thing, so I disabled them. My `Train` model needed a new field called `Description`, so I added it. I ran `Add-Migration AddDescriptionToTrains`, then did `Update-Database`. It's throwing me back this error:

```
Cannot find the object "dbo.Trains" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

I think this is happening because I deleted the `mdf` file that was under App_Data in order to wipe out my database and start fresh, and it doesn't have a migration to create the `Trains` table before it tried to add a `Description` field to it.

Basically my question is, can I delete all of my migrations down to `InitialCreate`, and then just generate one from my model? I only have one model so it should only create one migration. I just want to create the migration from the entire model, not what it thinks has changed in the model.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes you can. In my experience, anytime you can delete the content of the _MigrationsHistory table and restart generating migrations.